# Remove html element from a page loaded as ajax response into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am trying to remove a link(I want to make this as button please help in that too) with id=regbutton as soon as my index.jsp page is loaded as a response on clicking login button on regdata.jsp page

**regdata.jsp**

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#mainDiv").load("index.jsp");
        $('#regButton').remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" class="units-row">
<h2>Thanks For registering!</h2>
<button id="regLogin">Login Now</button>
</div>
```

**index.jsp**

```html
<body>
       <center>
         <s:actionerror />
         <h1 id="login_title"></h1>
         <form action="checkLogin.action" method="post">
            <p>
               <input type="text" id="username" name="username" 
                  placeholder="" >
            </p>
            <p>
               <input type="password" name="password" 
                  placeholder="" id="password">
            </p>
            <label> <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember"><label for="remember" id="rememberlbl"></label></label>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-log" method="execute"
               key="label_login"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
         </form>
         <a href="registerLogin.action" id="regButton">Register</a>         
      </center>
   </body>
```

Comment: Missing $ before ('#regButton')

Comment: Tried that still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function takes a second or third parameter - a callback function to execute when loading is done. So if you want the button to disappear only when the load completes you should move your code for it into that handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#mainDiv").load("index.jsp", function() {
          $('#regButton').remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfect due to less reputation i am unable to upvote your comments

Comment: I am facing one more issues as soon as i click the submit button a dropdown list(it is for internationalisation) is loaded onto my page again i.e i have two instances of the same dropdown of which one is static i.e it doesn't perform any operation

Comment: You may need to us jQuery's `.on()` function in order to attach events to elements that might not yet exist. I.e. `$(window).on("click", "button", function() { .... });` This way the code will be executed on all button elements even if they are added dynamically. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I can see a simple solution

```
#regButton
{
 display:none;
}
```

If this ain't sufficient i am working on a jquery solution as well